# Debug as root in VSCode under linux

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, real-time, visual-studio-code

The project I am developing needs to use one of linux real-time schedulers, for priority scheduling.
Since it needs root permission to change the scheduler to a real-time one, I changed the owner of the compiled program with root and set the SUID bit, so that when I try to execute it I gain the right permission to change the scheduler.

However, running it in debug mode under VSCode (using the gdb debugger) seems to ignore the SUID of the file, executing it with my underprivileged user.

How can I set up VSCode in order to execute gdb with root privileges?
Is there any other way than executing the whole VSCode as root to gain privileges only when debugging?